# Decoding text file using lists in Python

Tags: python, list, encoding, decoding

I encoded this sentence:

This is an amazing "abstract" AND this: is the end of this amazing abstract.

to this:

1 2 3 4 "5" 6 7: 2 8 9 10 7 4 5.

The corresponding index table (as text file) is:

```
word,index
This,1
is,2
an,3
amazing,4
abstract,5
AND,6
this,7
the,8
end,9
of,10
```

Now I want to go from these numbers:' 1 2 3 4 "5" 6 7: 2 8 9 10 7 4 5. ' to its corresponding words using the index table.

I used this code to open the index table text file as a sliced list:

```
index_file = open("decompress.txt", "r")

content_index = index_file.read().split()
print(content_index)
```

output:

```
['word,index', 'This,1', 'is,2', 'an,3', 'amazing,4', 'abstract,5', 'AND,6', 'this,7', 'the,8', 'end,9', 'of,10']
```

Then I sliced each element to a new list with this code:

```
for line in content_index:
    fields = line.split(",")
```

output:

```
['word', 'index']
['This', '1']
['is', '2']
['an', '3']
['amazing', '4']
['abstract', '5']
['AND', '6']
['this', '7']
['the', '8']
['end', '9']
['of', '10']
```

I tried decoding the numbers using fields[0] en fields[1] and for loops, but I did not succeed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This begs to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). You won't have to do any splitting, deal with the header row nor deal with indexes. Each "row" will become an dictionary with `'word'` and '`index'` keys. If needed, this list of dictionaries can then be converted to 2 dicts: one from word to index and the other from index to word

Comment: Please post the source code of what you've tried so far in decoding your strings and what errors you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's better to use dict and replace your code:

```
for line in content_index:
    fields = line.split(",")
```

to:

```
fields = {}
for line in content_index:
    word, number = line.split(',')
    fields[number] = word
```

Then you can use regular expressions to easily replace specific patterns (in your case — numbers) by any other strings. Regular expression for finding number will be `\d+` where `\d` means `digit` and `+` is for `one or more`
So:

```
import re

original_string = ' 1 2 3 4 "5" 6 7: 2 8 9 10 7 4 5. '

def replacement(match):
    """
    This function accepts regular expression match and returns corresponding replacement if it's found in `fields`
    """
    return fields.get(match.group(0), '')  # Learn more about match groups at `re` documentation.

result = re.sub(r'\d+', replacement, original_string)  # This line will iterate through original string, calling `replacement` for each number in this string, substituting return value to string.
```

So the final code will be:

```
import re

fields = {}

with open('decompress.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        word, number = line.split(',')
        fields[number] = word

original_string = ' 1 2 3 4 "5" 6 7: 2 8 9 10 7 4 5. '

def replacement(match):
    """
    This function accepts regular expression match and returns corresponding replacement if it's found in `fields`
    """
    return fields.get(match.group(0), '')

result = re.sub(r'\d+', replacement, original_string)
print(result)
```

You can learn more about regular expressions in Python documentation about `re` library. It's very powerful tool for text processing and parsing.

Answer (score 0):

For this instance, you can use regex from [re module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) and several [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehensions#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).

On first import re and get all lines to list:

```
import re

with open('decompress.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
#>> lines
# ['word,index\n', 'This,1\n', 'is,2\n', 'an,3\n', 'amazing,4\n', 
#  'abstract,5\n', 'AND,6\n', 'this,7\n', 'the,8\n', 'end,9\n', 'of,10']
```

After that use `re.search` with pattern `(.*)` - select anythink, `,` - before coma, and `(\d+)` - some digits after than. In this case skip the first line of document.

```
parsed_lines = [re.search(r'(.*),(\d+)', line) for line in lines if 'index' not in line]
```

And finally, create a dictionary with index is a key and text is a value.

```
fields = {int(line_match.group(2)): line_match.group(1) for line_match in parsed_lines}
# {1: 'This', 2: 'is', 3: 'an', 4: 'amazing', 5: 'abstract', 
#  6: 'AND', 7: 'this', 8: 'the', 9: 'end', 10: 'of'}
```

UPD: 
OR to list in the second step:

```
parsed_lines = [re.search(r'(.*),\d+', line).group(1) for line in lines if 'index' not in line]
```